# A specified logon session does not exist. it may already have been terminated outlook 365 error

Tags: outlook, office365

Unable to configure profile after installing Outlook 365.

It throws the error: **A specified logon session does not exist. it may already have been terminated**

[image: error-message]

Problem background:

I had a working Outlook 2016 which I uninstalled and installed the new Office 365 Outlook after which I'm unable to configure my Outlook profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer: Answering my own question, so that others shall not get stuck where I did.*

This error occurs due to conflict with previous left-over older Outlook configurations with the new Office365 Outlook.

I had to follow all these steps in the given order to resolve the issue.

---

**STEP - 1:**

Delete old Outlook profile *(Warning: You'll lose the local copy of all emails, on removing the profile)*

- Go to "Control Panel" --> "Mail" option.

  [image: Control Panel]
- Click on "Show Profiles"

  [image: Mail]
- Remove all profiles from there.

  [image: Mail Profiles]

---

**STEP - 2:**

Delete all files from the Accounts folder.

> C:\Users\rlal1\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin_cw5n1h2txyewy\AC\TokenBroker\Accounts

Delete everything present in the above directory. Restart your PC and try logging in to Outlook.

If it doesn't works follow the next steps.

---

**STEP - 3:**

Create a new Registry key

- Open Registry Editor and navigate to below registry path.

  > HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity
- Switch to the right-panel window and create a new key (DWORD 32-Bit value) with the following name  `DisableADALatopWAMOverride`.

  [image: Registry]
- Double-click on the value to change its Value Data from ‘0’ to ‘1’.

  [image: edit registry value - DisableADALatopWAMOverride]
- Now, create another new key (DWORD 32-Bit value) with the following name  `EnableADAL`.
- Double-click the entry and set its value to ‘0’.

  [image: edit registry value - EnableADAL]
- Finally, restart Windows and try to create a new Outlook profile again.

Comment: References > [refer to this document](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/outlook-specified-logon-session-does-not-exist/)